# Jetpack Compose - How to obtain the disabled/washed out look for a Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm building a custom chip in `Jetpack Compose` and I want to obtain the following look (regarding colors):

[image]

What grey colors are those? I've seen them all over material.io. And I assume that the first chip is obtained by applying some alpha modifier over the "original" chip. If so, how would I do it? And what would be the conventional alpha value to achieve this disabled look?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Modifier#alpha`

Set Alpha to `1.0f` when the chip is selected, `0.5f` otherwise

```
MyChip(modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (isSelected) 1.0f else 0.5f))
```

Comment: Yeah, but instead of  0.5f I think you could use `ContentAlpha.disabled`

Comment: Anything that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:
[image]

```
class ChipScreenActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ChipPreviewScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChipPreviewScreen() {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {

            Chip("Elevator", false)
            Chip("Dogs Ok", true)
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun Chip(name: String, status: Boolean) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50.dp))
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .background(
                if (status) Color.Gray else Color.LightGray
            )
    ){
        Row (
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        ){

            if (status){
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Check,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = Color.DarkGray
                )
            }

            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides (if (status) 1f else ContentAlpha.medium)) {
                Text(text = name)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ChipPreview() {
    ChipPreviewScreen()
}
```

Comment: What I was looking for were just the colors! And it seems like the right chip's color should be actually `Color.LightGray`. And I think that you should make them look disabled using the `alpha` modifier, together with the `ContentAlpha.disabled` or `ContentAlpha.medium` value

Comment: Actually, I didn't try ContentAlpha.disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is desaturation.

This code should get you started, you can desaturate any composable with this modifier:

```kotlin
Modifier.drawWithContent {
    drawIntoCanvas { composeCanvas ->
        composeCanvas.nativeCanvas.let { canvas ->
            val paint = android.graphics.Paint().also {
                it.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorMatrix().also { cm ->
                    cm.set(android.graphics.ColorMatrix(floatArrayOf(
                        0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f, 0f, 0f,
                        0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f, 0f, 0f,
                        0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f, 0f, 0f,
                        0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f
                    )))
                })
            }

            canvas.saveLayer(null, paint)

            try {
                drawContent()
            } finally {
                canvas.restore()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: inspired by [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/the-easiest-way-to-toggle-complete-layout-to-grayscale-on-android-fa86ac0a754) and the [corresponding code](https://github.com/alohaabhi/grayscale_experiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/grayscaleexperiment/ConstraintLayoutWithDisableSupport.kt).